# Function is exited when FIND does not return a result

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I want to have my own function, that is able to search the same area on several worksheets. My idea was to go through a set of sheets (here all sheets in the workbook) and use `Find` to search that area. Now if the search was successful on the first sheet, I don't want the result to be overwritten from the unsuccessful searches on the following, there for the if condition.

```
Function SheetsFind(LookUpValue As Integer) As Variant
    Dim SearchRange As Range

    For Each WS In Sheets
        Set SearchRange = WS.Range("A1:B6")

        If (SearchRange.Find(LookUpValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) <> "Nothing") Then
            SheetsFind = SearchRange.Find(LookUpValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next WS

End Function
```

The problem now is, if the find in the condition is unsuccessful, the function is left and I get a `#value` error.

Why does my function not just continue with the the next iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range.Find returns another range object, for this reason you're getting problems.

Try this:

```
Function SheetsFind(LookUpValue As Integer) As Variant

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim oResult As Excel.Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        Set SearchRange = ws.Range("A1:B6")

        Set oResult = SearchRange.Find(LookUpValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not oResult Is Nothing Then

            SheetsFind = oResult.Offset(0, 1).Value

        End If

    Next ws

End Function
```

Comment: If you are using this function as a worksheet function then you need to make it volatile, otherwise it will not recalculate when the data you are looking up changes. And I would probably add Exit Function after SheetsFind = oResult.Offset(0, 1).Value.